# Excel VBA running out of Memory but there is plenty of memory

Tags: vba, excel

i have this code:

```
Sub reportCreation()

Dim sourceFile As Variant
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim NValues As Long


If sourceFile = False Then
    MsgBox ("Select the MyStats file that you want to import to this report")
    sourceFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sourceFile)
    Set sourceSheet = wbSource.Sheets("Test Dummy Sheet")
    Set rng = sourceSheet.Range("A:N")
    rng.Copy

    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Set destSheet = wbDest.Sheets("MyStats")
    destSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wbSource.Close
End If

NValues = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With destSheet
    For i = 6 To NValues
       ' Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "0"
        With Cells(i, 3)
            .Value = Cells.Value / 1000000
            .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

the code runs fine for the IF Statement part which is a simple cop and paste sort of scenario but then once the WS has been copied to the new WB i need column 3 to devide any cell in that is larger than 1M by 1M and as soon as the code finds the first cell with a value of over 1M i get an error message "Runtime Error 7, system out of memory" but i still have 2GB left of memory so this does not seem to be your tipycal out of mem issue where i need to close a few applications and it will run because it just does not.
i am wondering if there is an issue with my code?

some of the sample values that the code will look are:

```
16000000
220000
2048000
230000
16000000
230000
16000000
```

Comment: In `.Value = Cells.Value / 1000000` the `Cells.Value` is an array of all values in the whole `ActiveSheet`. With an up to date Excel this are 2^20 * 2^14 cell values.

Comment: Perhaps you meant it to be `.Value = .Value / 1000000`

Comment: @chrisneilsen that was it mate!!!!.... thanks for that! i have been trying to find out whay i was running out of memory! if you put your comment inot an answer i will mark it as ";answer" straight away!

Comment: You also need to change `With Cells(i, 3)` to `With .Cells(i, 3)` (add a `.` before `Cells`). This should not be a problem in your case but you would reference your active worksheet without a `.` and that is not neccessary your `destSheet`. @chrisneilsen you should add your suggestion as an answer to close this question.

Comment: @FabianF dearly noted Fabian, i have made the amendments. thanks for your help so far as i believe that you have helped me on a couple of questions 'already!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to adopt a different approach like follows (see comments)

```
Option Explicit

Sub reportCreation()

    Dim sourceFile As Variant
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim tempCell As Range

    sourceFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select the MyStats file that you want to import to this report", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),") '<-- force user to select only excel format files

    If sourceFile = False Then Exit Sub '<-- exit if no file selected
    Set sourceSheet = TryGetWorkSheet(CStr(sourceFile), "Test Dummy Sheet") '<-- try and get the wanted worksheet reference in the chosen workbook
    If sourceSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<-- exit if selected file has no "Test Dummy Sheet" sheet

    With sourceSheet '<-- reference your "source" worksheet
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:N")).Copy
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyStats") '<-- reference your "destination" worksheet
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        sourceSheet.Parent.Close

        Set tempCell = .UsedRange.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, .UsedRange.Columns.Count) '<-- get a "temporary" cell not in referenced worksheet usedrange
        tempCell.Value = 1000000 'set its value to the wanted divider
        tempCell.Copy ' get that value into clipboard
        With .Range("C6:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row) '<-- reference cells in column "C" from row 6 down to last not empty one in column "B"
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationDivide '<-- divide their values by clipboard content
            .NumberFormat = "0.00" '<-- set their numberformat
        End With
        tempCell.ClearContents '<-- clear the temporary cell
    End With
End Sub

Function TryGetWorkSheet(wbFullName As String, shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set TryGetWorkSheet = Workbooks.Open(wbFullName).Sheets("Test Dummy Sheet")
End Function
```

Comment: WOW WOW WOW!  that is the most comprehensive and noob friendly piece of code that i have ever seen in my short career as a wanna be developer! thank you so much! do you offer free "brain picking" lessosns! i want to be like you one day!

Comment: you are welcome. glad it helped you. but please, change your wannabe reference asap!

Comment: not at all! but you've got to have really "high hopes"!

Comment: Oh you got me there! I thought I said a naughty word!